# NextJs - Node - API resolved without sending a response for /api/xxx

Tags: async-await, next.js, nodemailer

I have a nextjs app with a backend api where I am sending an email out.
I have seen a couple of other posts with the same issue, have tried their resolutions and not sure what I am missing.

Any insight is appreciated.

The code in the API is below.

```js
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    export default function (req, res) {
    
        const mailData = {
            from: 'xxxxx',
            to: req.body.email,
            subject: 'Message to Full On Consulting',
            text: req.body.message,
            html: '<div>'+req.body.message+'</div>'
        }
    
        sendMail(mailData)
        .then((result) => {
                console.log('Email sent...', result);
                res.status(200).json({ status: 'SUCCESS' })
            })
        .catch((error) => console.log('Error ... ' + error.message));
    }
    
    async function sendMail(mailData) {
      try {
    
        let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "mail.xxxxxxxxxx.com", 
              port: 587,
              secure: false,
            auth: {
              user: process.env.GMAIL_UID,
              pass: process.env.GMAIL_PW
            }
        });
    
        const result = await transport.sendMail(mailData)
    
        return result;
    
      } catch (error) {
            console.log("CATCH ERROR: " + error)
            return error;
      }`enter code here`
    }
```

Comment: What do you get for logs? Do any of the `catch` logs show up? Do you get in to the `then` block?

Comment: HI Ben, this is what I get in the log.   "API resolved without sending a response for /api/mailservice, this may result in stalled requests."

Comment: You need to add a `return` statement before the `sendMail` call, i.e. `return sendMail(mailData).then(...).catch(...)`. This will ensure the handler will wait for the promise to resolve before returning.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the sendmail call in a promise and that seems to have worked.

```js
    var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      let result = transport.sendMail(mailData);
      
    });

    promise.then( result => {
      console.log("PRomise Success ...");
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("Promise Failure...");
    });
```

Comment: Glad it worked! FYI, [you can use this syntax](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#syntax-highlighting) to get correct code display and formatting in your questions.